# Weird CTRL key detection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an input on one of my pages that has listeners on it that perform formatting on values entered into it.

The field only allows certain input(numerical as well as certain other characters), which is controlled with a keypress and a keyup listener. The keypress prevents illegal input, and the keyup performs formatting(and also checks input, in case the user pasted something into the field instead of typing).

It worked fine in Chrome and IE (back to IE8, I don't care about anything earlier), but in Firefox I was unable to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and was unable to copy or paste using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>

After some investigation I found that the problem lies with this listener:

`$(this).keypress(function(e)
{
    consumeIllegalFloatKeyPress(e);
});`

In IE and Chrome, keys like <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>arrows</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> weren't even triggering the listener, and keypresses like <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> would not trigger it either, when used with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. However, in FF it picks up all the keypresses, which resulted in
`consumeIllegalFloatKeyPress(e);`
getting called, and finding that the keypresses were illegal.

The fix was easy enough - I have an array of legal inputs that is used to check what should be allowed, so I just added the charCodes for <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd>, and put in a key for the `ctrlKey` as well.

What I am confused about is why these are being handled differently in different browsers? I thought that, since it was all javascript, that it would handle the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key the same across all browsers.

If anyone has any information on this, or knows of somewhere I can read up more on it, I'd be very interested and grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at official documentation:

[jQuery keypress listener](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

2 important things can be read here:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

And:

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "keypress", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "keypress" ) in the third.

Let's have a look at what the Javascript documentation says about keypress:

[javascript keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

After a few clicks we see a nice table on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

The table shows which browsers accepts certain keys, like non-printable keys (arrow keys, control, page down, ...) and which don't.

The final answer to your question is: if there is no set standard for something (like the keypress event), then browsers will do whatever they feel like doing. For Google chrome this means it allows `CTRL + V`, where Mozilla Firefox filters it.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks even more for providing your sources, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below solution. This works perfect for my issue

```js
function captureKeyPress(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var ctrlKeyPressed = e.ctrlKey;
    var key = e.which;
    switch(e.key){
      case "c": //right arrow key
        if (!ctrlKeyPressed) {
          alert('C pressed');
        }
        break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", captureKeyPress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
$(document).on("keypress", this, function (e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    /* Example */
    if (keycode === 27) {
         alert("Escape key");
    }
});
```

...and you can enable or disable keys what you whant.

I will give you one my function for this:

**FUNCTION:**

```
$.fn.pKey = function (key, callback) {
    var key=key;
    return this.each(function () {
        $(document).on("keypress", this, function (e) {
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (keycode === key) {
                callback.call(this, e);
            };
        });
    });
};
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$("#my-div").pKey(17,function (e) {
    /* disable CTRL*/
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already have an elegant solution for the problem. My question was just whether or not anyone actually knew exactly why this was happening :)

Comment: Can you put better exemple of your code? Somethimes `document` or `window` can made a problems and I need to look how you define `this` in your function. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, see the accepted answer below - I wasn't looking for a solution, just a reason why the code was working differently in different browsers.